# How to calculate days and float in one own function

Tags: python, pandas, date

i want calculate days and float in my function

so this is my dataframe

```
In[1]
df = {'Loan Nego': [2019-03-01, 2019-03-01], 'New Maturity': [2019-03-11, 2019-03-29],'Loan Amount in OCUR': [1000, 2000]}

Out[1]
Loan Nego          New Maturity          Loan Amount in OCUR   
2019-03-01         2019-03-11            1000
2019-03-01         2019-03-29            2000

In[2]
df.dtypes

Out[2]

New Maturity               datetime64[ns]
Loan Nego                  datetime64[ns]
Loan Amount in OCUR        float64
```

and i want to input this data frame into my function

```
# Equation CLOF
def clof(loan,maturity, amount):
days = (maturity-loan).days
return ((amount * days)/ 360) * (2.36/100)
```

i've tried but ther's is alert like this

*AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'*

```
df["New Interest"] = clof(df["Loan Nego"],df["New Maturity"],df["Loan Amount in OCUR"])
```

it doesn't work,

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days

**my expectation**

```
Loan Nego          New Maturity          Loan Amount in OCUR       New Interest 
2019-03-01         2019-03-11            1000                        0.65            
2019-03-01         2019-03-29            2000                        3.671
```

Ther's solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html), because working with `Series` in your function, not with scalars:

```
def clof(loan,maturity, amount):
    days = (maturity-loan).dt.days
    return ((amount * days)/ 360) * (2.36/100)

df["New Interest"] = clof(df["Loan Nego"],df["New Maturity"],df["Loan Amount in OCUR"])
print (df)
   Loan Nego New Maturity  Loan Amount in OCUR  New Interest
0 2019-03-01   2019-03-11                 1000      0.655556
1 2019-03-01   2019-03-29                 2000      3.671111
```